# Updating value in a column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter

This should be a really easy question, but I wanted to make sure it was done right where I'm not a SQL guy. We need to turn all of the patients with a security level of 1 to 2. All patients who are not at 1 are currently at 2. Thanks and sorry for asking such a simple question. SQL Server 2005.

```
select 

patient_id,
security_level

from patient
where security_level = '1'
```

[image]

Comment: `SET security_level=2` or `SET security_level=2 WHERE security_level=1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5fec/1)

```
update patient set security_level = '2' 
where security_level = '1';
```

Above will update the `entire` patient table, and set the security level to 2 (where it initially was 1).

Answer (score 1):

A simple update should work.  Something like:

```
UPDATE patient
SET sercurity_level='2'
WHERE security_level='1';
```

Edit: changed correct table name and added quotes

Comment: and what is different from my answer?

Comment: @MrSimpleMind - Could ask you the same.  Let's have a wonderful conversation about who clicked answer first and who pressed submit first.

Comment: sure, but normally I use to delete a duplicate answer if I m seconds later. But this is me. Cheers :)